# How to open a pipe between Matlab and Windows CMD (.NET?)

Tags: .net, windows, matlab, cmd, pipe

I have been using a python script that employs subprocess.Popen and subprocess.PIPE to open up a pipe between MATLAB and a windows cmd window.  However, I am moving this code to a system that cannot use python.  So, I am trying to figure out a way to replicate this process using only MATLAB.  So far, my research has gotten me to the point where I am fairly certain I need to implement .NET stuff using the System.IO.Pipes command in MATLAB, but I cannot figure out how to actually do it.  So, does anyone know how to pipe between matlab and cmd in windows?  Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to call OS command (either requesting output or not), please check the help of matlab 'system' command.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am attempting to do.  I know how to use the system command in matlab.  I am trying to open up a legitimate pipe between matlab and a specific cmd window so that I can have matlab send multiple inputs at varying times to the same cmd window.  System always opens a new cmd window as far as I am aware.